# Use GetTwitter 1.16.3 processor in Nifi gives error 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache-nifi, http-status-code-403

I did read the comments on the similar questions, checked out what the answers propose, followed those in detail. Does not change anything.
As I tried to do exactly the same in Python using the Tweepy library, and that does work fine, I know for sure it must be something at Nifi's side.
I do have elevated access on Twitter, I checked multiple times my tokens, they are correctly filled in.

Anybody a usefull answer?

Python code:

```
import tweepy 
consumer_key = 'xxx' 
consumer_secret = 'xxx' 
access_token = 'xxx' 
access_token_secret = 'xxx' 
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler( consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret ) 
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True) 
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="#twitter", count=100, tweet_mode='extended', until = '2022-07-09').items(): 
    text = tweet._json["full_text"] 
    print(text) 
    print('\n\n')
```

Nifi code:
Processor GetTwitter (1.16.3) with consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret filled correctly in.
Other elements not changed. Added a wait processor connected with success relation.

!! I retested the same simple flow (getTwitter and Wait processor)in version 1.12.1: result is a 401 error instead of 403(?)

Comment: Show your code in python and nifi processor configuration...

Comment: Please edit your question and put all information there